# walking randomly in $1D$, $2D$ and $3D$ place

Tags: probability

In our math book it is written that if you want to go to a random point in a $1D$ place and you randomly go right and left and also you have unlimited time finally you arrive at that point. Also in a $2D$ place you finally arrive there. But in a $3D$ place the chance to arrive there is 24%. It is really amazing but our book don't bring any proofs for it. How can we know this?

Comment: with the probability of $\frac{24}{100}$ you arrive that point in unlimited time.

Comment: @NP-hard.Our book is written by persion language you cannot understand it.

Comment: This was question #536 on this site -- I think this is the first time I encountered a three-digit question number :-) Note that while the duplicated question only explicitly adresses the low-dimensional cases, some comments and links under the answers also address the high-dimensional case.

Comment: @joriki.I want to know why we have the probability of $24$% on $3D$ walk.

Comment: It doesn't. [The MathWorld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolyasRandomWalkConstants.html) linked to in the other thread gives that probability as approximately $34\%$. If you're specifically looking for a proof of that probability, I'd suggest to edit the question to make that clear and to link to the existing thread on the low-dimensional cases -- shall I do that or do you want to do it?

Comment: Are you sure it is $34$% but I looked again in my book and it was $24$%.

Comment: Well, nowadays we have the Internet to check books. A brief search confirms that the typo is in your book and not in MathWorld.

Comment: Where have you looked I cannot find it.

Comment: Note that you automatically get notified when I write here because this is your question, but I don't get automatically notified when you write, so if you want to ask me something you need to ping me (using the @username construct). I'm off to lunch now but will post some links later.

Comment: In addition to [the MathWorld article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolyasRandomWalkConstants.html), there's [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#Higher_dimensions), [an OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A086230), [an MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/45098) and, since you seem to like those, [a book](https://books.google.de/books?id=LOUiWjsgue8C&pg=PT262&lpg=PT262&dq=3d+random+walk+return+probability&source=bl&ots=Scan_wJMJa&sig=0JaU7rl1ine9Ygb3G7byCzUSXdA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8v9eRxrnNAhWF3SwKHc_3BIw4HhDoAQgpMAI#v=onepage&f=false).

Comment: Note that the MathWorld article gives several references for the result. If you still want to ask how to prove it, I can reopen the question if you edit it to reflect the existing question on the low-dimensional cases; or let me know if you want me to do it.

Comment: @joriki. no it isn't needed.